# How to lock device orientation for React Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Hi I want to know how to lock device orientation for React Native for both android and iOS. I need to lock the orientation once user rotate the device and application will lock with portrait or lanscape

Comment: Try this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation-locker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Android**

For Android platform all we need to do is navigate to **AndroidManifest.xml** file that lies inside `android/app/src/main` path and add the property `android:screenOrientation` with a value or **portrait** or **landscape** respectively. The property has to be added in xml element activity which is a child of application element.

Simply add it as shown below:

[image]

**For iOS**

For iOS platform we need to open Xcode, and select the desired orientation modes from the Device Orientation section. As shown below:

1. Load the iOS part of your React Native project
2. Navigate to tab General from the horizontal menu
3. Go to down to Deployment Info section and check/uncheck the desired device orientation modes.

[image]

And you are set! Rebuild your project to verify that the changes are configured.

Comment: @DeSilva glad it helps